# What CUDA version for VS2017 and GTX 870M?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, visual-studio-2017

I want to develop a program using CUDA but I am getting lost by install instructions on [NVidia's site](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html).

So here is what I have:

- Windows 10 laptop with a NVidia GPU GeForce GTX 870M
  (both OS and GPU driver are up to date)
- Visual Studio 2017, Version 15.8 (also up to date) _MS_VER=1915

On [this webpage](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), I found out that my GPU is CUDA enabled (good news) with "Compute capability" 3.0. **What does it mean?**

I know that CUDA versions are sensitive to the version of Visual Studio used, so
my question is simple:

- **what version of CUDA should I download and install? and can I build and run programs with my version of Visual Studio?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no version of the CUDA Toolkit currently supports Visual Studio 15.8. The latest CUDA 9.2 supposedly supports up to Visual Studio 15.6. Note that the issue of Visual Studio support really only concerns the NVCC compiler and Visual Studio Integration. There's nothing preventing you from, e.g., using the CUDA Driver API with whatever compiler you wish (including the latest version of VS).

One way around these issues used to be to put your CUDA code into a separate static library, build that with the VS 2015 compilers, and link it to the main project which could be built using VS 2017.

Make sure you have selected the `VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop` package in Visual Studio Installer:

[image: visual studio installer]

You can then switch the toolset to use for each project in Project Properties > General:

[image]

Unfortunately, I've recently encountered some issues with linking binaries built with VS 2015 to binaries built with the VS 2017 15.8 compilers, so that path might no longer work (seemed to be related to the new "Just My Code Debugging" feature). But then, binary compatibility across compiler versions was never really something to rely on in the first place…

Another solution would be to [downgrade your Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017) to 15.6.

---

The compute capability of a device basically tells you what generation of GPU architecture you're dealing with and which features you can rely on. Or in the words of the [CUDA Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability):

> The compute capability of a device is represented by a version number, also sometimes called its "SM version". This version number identifies the features supported by the GPU hardware and is used by applications at runtime to determine which hardware features and/or instructions are available on the present GPU.

More details on individual compute capabilities/architectures can be found, e.g., [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-3-0).